# loading a view on top of tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, ios4

I have a tabbar controller and on touching a button in one of view's navigation right button i want to load a (nav controller + view )on top of it. The view which is on the top of it is semi transparent and i should be able to see the content in the tabbar controller.

I tried using the [self.tabbarcontroller.view addSubview:navController];

I worked perfectly and it is working fine. But when i tried to do the same thing in landscape view it is just occupying half the screen. what should be done ? is there a way to fix this issue

can i use the window to load my new view ? will it occupy the entire screen ? i tried autoresize masks and there is no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the bounds of the navController/tabbarcontroller?  Are you setting correctly to that of the window?

You can output it easily:

```
NSLog(@"navController bounds: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(navController.view.bounds));
```

Comment: it is 0,0 320,460. I actually manually set it as 0,0,460,320 using drawRect method and frame property of uiview. It has no effect. :(

Comment: i set the bounds and frame of the view after adding to the navigation controller. That helped me. Your idea to watch the bounds really helped me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `addSubview:navController.view`? I didn't think you could treat view controllers as views.

In general, you need to be careful when using UIViewController outside of the framework-managed classes. UIKit automatically handles stuff like viewWillAppear/autorotation for the view controllers that it knows about, but it doesn't know about the VCs whose views you randomly add as subviews.

**EDIT:** If all you require is that it appears to be transparent, you can use something like

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tabBarController.view.size, 0, 0);
[tabBarController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and then use img as the view background. It won't animate the stuff in the background, but provided you don't need this, it's *much* faster than having lots of transparent views stacked on top of each other.